# Double.parseDouble() Exception

Tags: java, android, double, numberformatexception, decimalformat

I have this DecimalFormat:

```
DecimalFormat formatSci = new DecimalFormat("#.#########E0");
```

When I have

```
text.append(formatSci.format(answer));//answer is a double value
```

and after that:

```
double b = Double.parseDouble(text.toString());//text is something like 2.3333333E10
```

It throws NumberFormatException. What is wrong with this as apparently it works on android 4.4.4 and above and not on older versions?

Comment: `System.out.println(Double.parseDouble("2.3333333E10"));` works correctly so something is wrong elsewhere.

Comment: Could the problem be in the DecimalFormat?

Comment: DecimalFormat formatSci = new DecimalFormat("#.#########E0");
double b = Double.parseDouble(formatSci.format(2.3333333E10));                 This doen't work though.

Comment: This is a locale problem, see @Priyank answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may happen because of your internal Locale specification.

Try using:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
Number number = format.parse(text.toString());
double d = number.doubleValue();
// OR
double d = Double.parseDouble(text.toString());
```